# Remove any file that is not a folder

Tags: windows-7, command-line, compression

I have a complex directory in my work and another person needs it's structure. Having so many directories, instead of manually documenting, he insisted just duplicate that folder, then remove all the files and then compress the whole directory in a `*.zip` file. Compressing it is easy, but how can I remove the files? I believe using the command line is the way but I don't know how to start. Its on a Windows OS by the way.

Comment: Perhaps deleting everything that has an extension? Something like `DEL [/options] "Path\*.*"` Using wildcards and a dot. Not 100% certain how it works, so just suggesting.

Comment: Actually command line `DEL /Q /F /S "X:\RootFolder\*"` will do the trick for deleting recursively and NOT including any directories whether there is a file with an extension or not (files only).  Otherwise, the compression tool you use may have some switch or option to delete the files once compressed so you'd want to check it's help file, etc.  Specifically for deleting files only, just create a dummy folder with some dummy data and folder structure, etc. and then check with the syntax and command I provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to copy all the directory files included, you should copy only the tree structure with the command

```
 xcopy SourceDir DestinationDir /T /E
```

where

> **/e**
>    Copies all subdirectories, even if they are empty. Use /e with the /s and  /t command-line options.
>
> **/t**
>   Copies the subdirectory structure (that is, the tree) only, not files. **To copy empty directories, you must include the `/e` command-line option.**

**Reference**

- The *technet* site of Microsoft for the [xcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx) command
- The [mswindows-forum](http://www.ozzu.com/mswindows-forum/copy-zip-directory-structure-only-t68389.html) on this specific question